# how to customize searchView with Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, customization, searchview

Using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar with the searchView.
When using Theme.AppCompat.Light, the searchView cursor, textColor, hint becomes black, and has blue underline.

I have custom toolbar background color, which needs to have the searchView to have white color.
I managed to get the icon, text to be white, and cursor, but not sure how to make the hint white, and the underline as well.
And not sure what I did is right or may have impact on other places.
Anyone has suggestion?

```
<style name="myAppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      .....
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/mySearchViewStyle</item>
    <-- for search text -->
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <-- for cursor -->
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/white_cursor</item>
</style>

<!--  -->
<style name="mySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/icon_close</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/icon_search</item>
</style>
```

I saw in 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-mr2-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java

it referring the textView by R.id.search_src_text, is it safe to use it to get the textView?

```
public SearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     ....
    mQueryTextView = (SearchAutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`? That gives you white by default.

Comment: thanks  ianhanniballake. in a few places the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar brings in some style do not work well with our customization than using Theme.AppCompat.Light.